# Why does JVM convert an `OR` to `AND`?

Tags: java, compilation

I am checking if an `object` is having an epoch pattern or is of type `Long`. So I wrote this in Java 8:

```
if(currentValue.toString().matches(EPOCH_PATTERN.pattern()) || 
currentValue instanceof Long) 
        this.setValue(Long.valueOf(currentValue.toString()));
      else
        this.setValue(currentValue);
```

and JVM compiled it to

```
if (!currentValue.toString().matches(EPOCH_PATTERN.pattern()) && 
!(currentValue instanceof Long)) {
                this.setValue(currentValue);
            } else {
                this.setValue(Long.valueOf(currentValue.toString()));
            }
```

This is definitely not what I expected when I wrote the code.
How does `OR` get changed to `AND`. Am I making a fundamental mistake here?

Comment: Are you aware of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)? If you do, what kind of answer are you expecting here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind this:

- If you think that your logic is better then a code that was revied and tested by hundreds, then you are wrong
- If you think there is a bug in an open-source code then think twice, highly possible that you are wrong

**Lets suppose this:**

```
A: currentValue.toString().matches(EPOCH_PATTERN.pattern()
B: currentValue instanceof Long
```

**Your code**

```
A = 0 and B = 1 ---> 0 || 1 = 1 ---> setValue(Long...)
A = 1 and B = 0 ---> same case
A = 1 and B = 1 ---> same case
A = 0 and B = 0 ---> 0 || 0 = 0 ---> setValue(currentValue)
```

**JVM code**

```
A = 0 and B = 1 ---> !0 && !1 ---> 1 && 0 = 0 ---> setValue(Long...)
A = 1 and B = 0 ---> !1 && !0 ---> same case
A = 1 and B = 1 ---> !1 && !1 ---> same case
A = 0 and B = 0 ---> !0 && !0 ---> 1 && 1 = 1 --> setValue(currentValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

It didn't just change OR to AND, it changed `A || B` to `!(!A && !B)`, which is a standard Boolean logic substitution. Note that the outer `not` was done by swapping around the `if` and `else` blocks.

I would assume this is a compiler optimization. Don't worry about it.